# SpringBoot Keycloak NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplates

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, javax

I probably have an issue with my POM in my SpringBoot App.

Currently I am trying to access my Keycloak Server with the 
"admin-client-keycloak"

But on the call:

```
Response response = getInstance().realm(REALM).users().create(user);
```

I get Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplates(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.resolveTemplates(ClientWebTarget.java:178) ~[resteasy-client-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.SubResourceInvoker.invoke(SubResourceInvoker.java:65) ~[resteasy-client-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-3.5.1.Final.jar:3.5.1.Final]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.realm(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realm(Keycloak.java:118) ~[keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
```

To be honest: I am not a Maven expert and stitched it together from several web soultions and I expect that some parts are still outdated or something.

the POM dependecys:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Keycloak -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The Error occurs from the 'keycloak-admin-client' module.

Now the main question is:

- Whats the problem? Or is it realy a bug inside the version of 'keycloak-admin-client'?

I guess not which leads my to a second question:

- How can I found out what I need to change in a situation like this?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions. I primary want to learn how to solve such issues by my own in future.

Kind regards
Gregor

**EDIT:**

Well I am a step further but the issue is still there.

The POM I show you here is a POM of library which is used in other projects.
These Project have a 'spring-Boot-starter' which are using the 'jersey' version:1.54.

So the problem seems clear. 
I added the 'jersey 2.0.2' dependency in the final project POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But the issue still exists. 
How can I force maven use the 2.0.2 version and override the 1.5.?

Only adding the dependecy doesnt seems to help.

Answer (score 23):

Some of the other dependencies are using a different version of the lib jsr311-api. In my case it was the eureka client. I just added an exclude with this dependency in the pom and it worked

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for my issue. You saved my day, thank you :)

Comment: I had to follow this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738748/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-uribuilder-resolvetemplatesljava

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure **UriBuilder** class exist on your project. And make sure only one **UriBuilder** class (version) exist in your project. (It can be multiple on your project with different versions.) Different versions can be overlapped.

1. keycloak-admin-client version should same with your keycloak server version.
2. add additional dependency to pom (**versions must be added**, for keycloak 3.0.0.Final => resteasy dependecies 3.5.0.Final works for me. Dependencies must be complied.)

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
           <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   ```

Note: This is my suggestion, if you are develop multi-layer app. You can divide your project to layers. You can divide your spring boot starter app and keycloak access layer. And use this new project as dependecy.

edit,

see [Failed adding user by keycloak-admin-client to Keycloak due to "unknown resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320163/failed-adding-user-by-keycloak-admin-client-to-keycloak-due-to-unknown-resource)

i hope these can helps.