# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplates(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud, jhipster-gateway, keycloak-admin-cli

I'm trying to use spring boot keycloak client and admin into microservice contains spring cloud,
I get this error when I want to create a user from keycloak admin api
Thanks for you support

error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplates(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:57)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
```

/* source */

```
private RealmResource getRealmResource() {
        this.keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
                serverURL,
                realmkeycloak,
                usernamekeycloak,
                passwordKeycloak,
                clientIdkeycloak);
        return keycloak.realm(globalRealm);  
    }
```

***Maven Tree:***

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ onboardingms ---
[INFO] com.xxxxxx:onboardingms:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.xxxxxx:commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.2-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:jar:5.4.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zalando:problem-spring-web:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.zalando:problem-violations:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.zalando:problem-spring-common:jar:0.25.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.zalando:problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.zalando:jackson-datatype-problem:jar:0.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.zalando:faux-pas:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.10.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.10.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.10.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-serialization:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava-reactive-streams:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.stoyanr:evictor:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:10.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:10.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix:jar:10.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-connectors-core:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-heroku-connector:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-localconfig-connector:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-data:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.3.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.8.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-spring:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-2-adapter:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.keycloak:spring-boot-container-bundle:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-spi:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.62:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:jar:9.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.9.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.9.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:jar:1.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.9.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.9.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.9.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.fge:json-patch:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |           \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |              \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:2.0.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.3.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.3.8.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:2.0.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:jar:2.0.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

- Keycloak server is running
- user and password are checked
- maven build success
- Api is running
- create user api is KO

Answer (score 2):

it's resolve it by :

adding this exclusion :

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

and upgrading jersey

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```